# Predicting certain independent events (each have a known probability)

Tags: probability

Consider 15 independent events, each of these events can have three states (for example they can be 1, 2 or 3).

Now for example in the event one there is 20% chance of getting 1, 45% of getting 2 and 35% of getting 3. Each event has its own probability.

Now the goal is I want to predict all 15 events correctly, I must choose at least a number (1,2 or 3) for each event. But I am able to choose 10 events and select another number. For example at the beginning I for event one I chose number 3 to happen.

Now I choose number 2 too, so that unless event 1 happens I am right about event 1. Imagine that you can choose 100 different variation in this way.

How should I choose them so the probability of me predicting all the events will be maximum?

Comment: well, if I understood correctly, the naive answer (considering the events are independent), will be to to put your 25 chooses on the 25 highest probabilities.

Comment: and BTW, it is not 100 different variations...if I'm not mistaken, you have total ${15 \choose 10} * {3 \choose 1}^5 * {3 \choose 2}^{10}$ different variations you can choose.

Comment: Well sure one of the forms can be the one with highest probability, but keep in mind you can have more forms.

Comment: Can you rephrase the problem? I don't have a clear understanding of what you are asking (e.g. "But I am able to choose 10 events and select another number.")

Comment: Sure, there are imagine it like this. We have a dice with number 1 2 and 3. But the probability of landing on 1, 2 or 3 are different. For example 15% of the times you get 1, 20 % you get 2 and 65% you get 3. Now you toss it 15 times but each of these 15 times has different percentages (known) and are independent. Now you are free to make a form and predict how it is going to be when you toss it 15 times. Your predictions has these rules:1) must at least select one from each event 2. you have 10 extra prediction but you can only predict 2 out of 3 possible ways.

Comment: thise matrix is the result for example (1     0     0,
     1     0     0,
     0     0     1,
     0     1     0,
     0     1     0,
     0     0     1,
     1     0     0,
     0     0     1,
     0     1     0,
     1     0     0,
     0     1     0,
     1     0     0,
     1     0     0,
     1     0     0,
     1     0     0)

Comment: and your choice would be something like this ( 1     0     1,
     1     0     1,
     1     0     0,
     0     1     1,
     1     1     0,
     1     0     1,
     1     1     0,
     1     0     0,
     1     0     1,
     1     0     1,
     0     1     1,
     1     0     0,
     1     1     0,
     1     0     0,
     1     0     0)